# Finding speed of light by $c=f\lambda$?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, wave-particle-duality

When considering EM radiation as waves it is said that it is electric and magnetic fields that oscillate with time. Therefore $f$ is not frequency of distance but of electromagnetic fields.

I have also been taught to derive  wavelength from the equation $c=f\lambda$. However this raises a question: if $f$ is not frequency of oscillation of distance and $\lambda$ is measure of distance isn't the equation $c=f\lambda$ bogus in the first place?

Comment: Can you please explain what "frequency of distance" means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, for a wave with speed $v$ and frequency $f$, the wavelength is given by,

$$\lambda = \frac{v}{f}$$

In our case, for light or electromagnetic radiation, $v=c$. Hence, if we measure some incoming radiation which has frequency $f$, and wavelength $\lambda$, it must hold,

$$c=\lambda f$$

or roughly, as our measurements have uncertainties. Dimensionally, the equation is perfectly fine; notice that $[f]=\mathrm{s}^{-1}$ and $[\lambda]=\mathrm{m}$, hence $[\lambda f]=\mathrm{ms}^{-1}$ which is precisely velocity as required.

---

Alternatively, recall the energy of a photon with frequency $f$ is given by, $E=hf$ where $h$ is Planck's constant. Hence we could express the speed of light, $c$, as
$$c=\frac{E\lambda}{h}$$

with $E$ being the energy we measure, and $\lambda$ once again the wavelength. For example, for ultraviolet light, we know $E$ is large (in comparison to the other end of the spectrum), which implies a low $\lambda$.